# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scopes'

Tags: python, typeerror

I am new to Microsft-User-Application. I have no prior knowledge about it, trying to learn.
I used this source code: https://github.com/areed1192/ms-graph-python-client
This is my code:

```
import configparser
from unittest import TestCase
from configparser import ConfigParser
from ms_graph.client import MicrosoftGraphClient

scopes = [
    'Calendars.ReadWrite',
    'Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared',
    'Directory.Read.All',
    'Directory.ReadWrite.All',
    'Files.ReadWrite',
    'Files.ReadWrite.All',
    'Notes.ReadWrite.All',
    'offline_access',
    'User.Read',
    'User.Read.All',
    'User.ReadWrite.All'
]

Config = ConfigParser()

Config.read(r'B:/New_folder/Graph_Download/Secret.ini')

client_id = Config.get('graph_api', 'client_id')
client_secret = Config.get('graph_api', 'client_secret')
redirect_uri = Config.get('graph_api', 'redirect_uri')

Mgraph_client = MicrosoftGraphClient(
    client_id= client_id,
    client_secret= client_secret,
    redirect_uri= redirect_uri,
    scopes= scopes,
    credentials= 'B:/New_folder/Graph_Download/Settings.jsonc'
)


Mgraph_client.login()
```

[& this is my API permission:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sQbU.png)

when I run my code it provides 'TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scopes''

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: The parameter name is `scope`, not `scopes`.

Comment: This issue resolves, thanks @chepner